# Vuex getters forEach returns single value instead of multiple

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a cart, and it's an array of products, I am trying to access every name in the cart.
I have forEach function in getters, but it returns just one name. I have tried.map() but it returns another array and I need multiple string values. Can you please help?

```
let cart = window.localStorage.getItem('cart')

const store = createStore({
    state: {
        
        cart: cart ? JSON.parse(cart) : [],
        

    },


 getters: {
   setTitle: state =>{
           let oneItem=''
            state.cart.forEach((item)=>{
                oneItem=item.ropeTitle
            })

            return oneItem
        },
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're returning just `oneItem` (let me guess, it's also the last item in the `state.cart` array as well?)

What you can try instead is using `.join()` to join the item together.

Let's say you want to join items by `,` , you can try

```js
setTitle: state => state.cart.map(item => item.ropeTitle).join(', ')
```